# SendXMPP on Ubuntu server 12.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, xmpp

I'm trying to configure sendxmpp on my ubuntu server 12.04 LTS to use it to send notification from Munin/monitoring to Gtalk.

Installed the app with the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install sendxmpp
```

try to do some test/chat, but its failed to do some with some error below:

```
$ echo "This is a gtalk test" | sendxmpp -t -u user1 -o gmail.com -p pa55word user2@gmail.com

Use of uninitialized value $args{"file"} in lc at /usr/share/perl5/Net/XMPP/Debug.pm line 154.
```

I dont have any clue what actually the error is about:

```
"Use of uninitialized value $args{"file"} in lc at /usr/share/perl5/Net/XMPP/Debug.pm line 154."
```

Even execute help command shown this error:

```
$ sendxmpp --help

Use of uninitialized value $args{"file"} in lc at /usr/share/perl5/Net/XMPP/Debug.pm line 154.
sendxmpp version 1.22
Copyright (c) 2004 - 2005 Dirk-Jan C. Binnema
Copyright (c) 2006 - 2007 Lubomir Host 'rajo'
usage: sendxmpp [options] <recipient1> [<recipient2> ...]
or refer to the the sendxmpp manpage
```

Possibly [some kind of bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=626897)?

Comment: That looks like a non-fatal warning. I'm assuming that the message doesn't get delivered? Has user1 been added to user2's roster?

Comment: its already added, but still no message :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "uninitialized value" message is a harmless warning; you can ignore it.

It seems that `sendxmpp` doesn't look at `SRV` records, and so you need to explicitly tell it to connect to `talk.google.com`. You also need to make sure that user1 is in user2's roster (i.e. you've sent and accepted a contact request).

It's also better to store the password in the configuration file instead of specifying it on the command line. Enter the following in `~/.sendxmpprc` and `chmod` the file `600`:

```
user1@gmail.com;talk.google.com     pa55word    gmail.com
```

You should then be able to send messages with `sendxmpp -t user2@gmail.com`.